# Who pays for the expenses of players called up during international breaks?

Tags: rules, football, finances, fifa

Does FIFA pay for the expenses of a player (flight, etc.) when the national team call the player for a friendly or a competition in FIFA calendar?

Does it depend on the division that such a player is in?

For example, suppose Haiti wants to call some players for a game in the CONCACAF Nation's League, one from France Ligue 1 and others from Spanish Segunda/Segunda B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

FIFA doesn't cover travel or any logistic expenses of international **friendly** matches, because they are coordinated between corresponding associations.

FIFA covers only travel costs for referees and its own representatives of the **qualification** games.

FIFA covers part of travel or logistic expenses during **final** tournaments, e.g. FIFA World Cup.

There's no mention in FIFA regulations about the division of the player in which he plays.

---

**Long answer:**

The settlement of the costs of 2 associations playing during **qualification** phase *recommended* by FIFA is described in [**2018 FIFA World Cup Regulations - Preliminary competition - 27 Financial provisions**](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/02/84/35/19/regulationsfwc2018en_neutral.pdf#page=40):

> 3. [...] FIFA recommends the following provisions:
>
> a) the visiting association shall cover its delegation’s own
>   international travel costs to the venue or the nearest airport, as
>   well as board, lodging costs and incidental expenses;
>
> b) the host association shall cover domestic transport costs for the
>   entire official delegation of the visiting team depending on flight
>   connections (cf. art. 21 par. 1);
>
> c) the host association shall pay for board and lodging in a
>   high-standard hotel and domestic transport in the host country for the
>   match officials, the FIFA Match Commissioner, the referee assessor
>   and any other FIFA officials (i.e. security officer, media officer
>   etc.);
>
> [...]
>
> 5. FIFA shall bear the costs of:
>
> a) international travel and the daily allowances, as fixed by FIFA,
>   for the referees, assistant referees and fourth offi cials;
>
> b) international travel and the daily allowances for the respective
>   FIFA delegation members, as fixed by FIFA.

The settlement of the costs during **final competition** is described in [**2018 FIFA World Cup Regulations - Final competition - 50 Financial provisions**](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/02/84/35/19/regulationsfwc2018en_neutral.pdf#page=64):

> 1. The participating member associations shall be responsible for and bear the costs of the following:
>
> a) adequate insurance to cover their Team Delegation Members and any
>   other persons carrying out duties on their behalf against all risks,
>   including but not limited to injury, accident, disease and travel in
>   consideration of the applicable FIFA rules or regulations;
>
> b) board and lodging during the final competition, including rental of
>   meeting rooms and audio/visual technical equipment, in excess of the
>   contribution paid by FIFA;
>
> c) costs associated with additional members of the association’s
>   delegation (in excess of the 50 official Team Delegation Members).
>
> 2. The Organising Association shall, in accordance with the HA, organise and bear the costs of all domestic travel (road, rail or air)
>      for each official Team Delegation Member of each participating member
>      association (maximum of 50 people per participating member
>      association), including their equipment (up to a maximum weight to be
>      defi ned by FIFA at a later stage).
> 3. FIFA shall bear the costs of the following:
>
> a) a contribution towards the preparation costs incurred by the
>   participating member associations in accordance with a set tariff to
>   be fixed in duecourse by the FIFA Organising Committee;
>
> b) business-class return fl ights for 50 people from each
>   participating member association between a city to be designated by
>   the FIFA Organising Committee and the first point of arrival in the
>   host country. For each delegation’s international air travel to the
>   2018 FIFA World Cup Russia™ FIFA may request the participating member
>   associations to use either (i) the airline notified to the
>   participating member associations as being FIFA’s designated air
>   carrier or (ii) an appropriate network alliance partner of such
>   designated air carrier (if the designated air carrier does not service
>   the international airports of any participating member association).
>   If, contrary to any such request by FIFA, any participating member
>   association elects not to use FIFA’s designated air carrier or an
>   appropriate network alliance partner of such designated air carrier,
>   or if any participating member association elects to charter a private
>   aircraft for the air travel of its delegation, FIFA’s obligation will
>   be limited to the amount FIFA would have incurred had the
>   participating member association used FIFA’s designated air carrier
>   for its delegation’s air travel;
>
> c) a contribution towards the costs of board and lodging for 50 people
>   from each participating member association in accordance with a set
>   tariff to be fixed in due course, starting five days prior to each
>   team’s first match and ending no later than the second day following
>   the team’s elimination. The FIFA Organising Committee shall determine
>   these rates based on an average of the prevailing FIFA World Cup™
>   sales rates in the official team hotels;
>
> d) prize money for the participating member associations, the amounts
>   of which shall be determined by FIFA;
>
> e) the costs incurred by match offi cials, referee assessors and FIFA
>   Match Commissioners and other members of the FIFA delegation;
>
> f) doping control expenses;
>
> g) the costs of insurance taken out by FIFA to cover its own risks.
>
> [...]
>
> 5. Any expenses and costs incurred by a participating member association other than those mentioned in these Regulations shall be
>      borne by the participating member association concerned.

Comment: World Cup 18 has nothing to do with Concacaf Nations League, since CNL won't even start until after WC18. How does this address the example?

Comment: I gave a more general answer. The reference to CNL in OP's question was just one example, and sadly CNL didn't even publish tournament regulations.

Comment: But the WC is only one competition among many. Where does it address all of the others, CNL being only one example that is not.

Answer (score -2):

It's national federation who payed, but it can be the team of the player with private airplane too

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE, please try to back up your answer with sources/references, as comment-like answers are highly discouraged in our platform. Here you can see a section in our Help Center on [How to write a good answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).